# Estoy intentando listar elementos en django teniendo una conexion api soap

Tags: html5, django, api

Soy nuevo en esto de pagina web + api y el problema que estoy teniendo es a la hora de listar 1 departamento en especifico para asi mostrar sus elementos en la pagina web. el problema es que la respuesta soap es positiva y me muestra todos los elementos en la terminal mediante un print pero no me los visualiza en la pagina web. De antemano muchas gracias

Función para obtener la lista de departamento.

```
def obtener_precio_departamento(id_departamento):
    try:

        cliente = zeep.Client(API_URL)

        response = cliente.service.listarDepaPorId(id_departamento)

        print("Respuesta del servicio SOAP:", response)

        if response and isinstance(response, dict) and 'precio' in response:
            return response['precio']
        else:
            return None
    except zeep.exceptions.Fault as e:
        print("Error en la llamada SOAP:", str(e))
        return None
```

Views.py de mi pagina web

```
def reserva(request):
    precio_departamento = obtener_precio_departamento(1)

    if precio_departamento is not None:
        print("Precio del departamento:", precio_departamento)
    else:
        print("No se pudo obtener el precio del departamento.")

    return render(request, 'reserva.html', {'precio_departamento': precio_departamento, 'user_info': request.session.get('user_info')})
```

Html

```
{% if precio_departamento %}
  <p class="precio">CLP ${{ precio_departamento }}</p>
{% else %}
  <p>No se encontró información del departamento.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Me da la respuesta de la api la cual es de la función pero después para llamarla en mi archivo html no se me visualiza, esta seria lo que me imprime en la terminal

```
Respuesta del servicio SOAP: {
    'cantidad_img': 3,
    'capacidad_persona': 2,
    'descripcion': 'gfffd',
    'direccion': 'xcdfdfdfxc',
    'id_comuna': 50,
    'id_departamento': 1,
    'id_estado': 2,
    'latitud': 37.7749,
    'longitud': -122.4194,
    'precio': 100
}
No se pudo obtener el precio del departamento.
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui un par de recomendaciones

1. **Error en la llamada al servicio SOAP:** Verifica que la llamada al servicio SOAP esté funcionando correctamente. Puedes agregar más mensajes de depuración para asegurarte de que estás recibiendo una respuesta válida del servicio. Además, asegúrate de que API_URL esté definida correctamente y que el servicio SOAP esté en línea y accesible.
2. **Plantilla HTML:** La plantilla HTML que proporcionaste parece estar bien, pero asegúrate de que el contexto que pasas a render esté configurado correctamente. Verifica que precio_departamento esté siendo pasado al contexto y que el nombre de la variable en la plantilla (precio_departamento) coincida con el nombre en la vista (precio_departamento).
3. Verifica que no haya errores de sintaxis en `reserva.html`
4. Comprueba que el valor que estas pasando en `precio_departamento = obtener_precio_departamento(1)` tenga un registro de `departamento` asociado.